# Explanation of monerod `status` command

Tags: monerod

Most of `status` is self explanatory.  But there are a couple I don't understand. I'm a complete n00b to both monero and crypto mining in general so forgive me if these are all rather elementary. I couldn't find much in terms of explanations .

- `net hash` - why is this a rate? Don't understand how a rate has a 'net' value.
- `connections` - 0(out)+48(in) is what I have right now.  What are these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "net" stands for network, ie network hash rate. Now that you mention it, I will go make a PR to change it to be more clear.

The (out) connections are those where your computer initiated the connection with some other node.

The (in) connections are those where other node initiated the connection with your computer.

They're all fully qualified connections, the difference is just in the "who called who?".