# Meaning of monerod status command output

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands, stagenet

I use `Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.3.0-release)` CLI only.

I would really like to know the meaning of a `status` command output line like this:
`Height: 146124/146124 (100.0%) on stagenet, mining at 36 H/s, net hash 268 H/s, v7, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 11m 57s`

I could not find anything specific.

In fact everything is clear to me but the following:

- `V7`
- `8(out)+0(in) connections`

What I am really interested in is the meaning of `V7`, since I also have daemons running (same monero release) which show `V1` instead and they continuously produce lines like these:

`[94.19.172.18:51393 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 136994 -> 250777 [Your node is 113783 blocks (79 days) behind]`

or

`[207.180.196.236:57862 INC]  peer claims higher version that we think (9 for 232290 instead of 7) - we may be forked from the network and a software upgrade may be needed`

Comment: I found [this thread](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/explanation-of-monerod-status-command?rq=1) explaining a few of the information pieces but not all of them.

Comment: I have a question to the status as well. If one uses login credentials to access the node, shouldn't the node status always display 0(in) since it tells you the number of **currently active** connections? (assuming that nobody knows the username and password and I am not logged in)

Comment: Try to ask a new question, instead of answering an old question, which is already answered :)

Comment: As far as I know, this is not the number of clients connected to your node, but the number of other nodes connected to your node. See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/explanation-of-monerod-status-command).

Comment: Alright, I promise to improve on that :). But I didn't find the article that you linked to. Thanks for that! Just to be clear: even though I password protect the node, other nodes can sync the blockchain from my node, right? The credentials are just a gate to peers, who try to snyc their wallet? Well, just out of curiosity. I only password protected it at the beginning and want to leave it open to the network once everything works well for a couple of days.

Comment: These are user and password for the daemon RPC, I guess. When you search for monerod documentation on the web, you'll find the rpc documentation. I don't have the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1 means the blockchain is currently at version 1. v7 means it's at version 7. If the blockchain is syncing (as shown by monerod telling you it's currently 79 days behind), it'll show the version at the point it's reached so far. At this time, the network should be at version 7.

The "peer claims higher version that we think" message is telling you that a peer on the network is running a later version. Normally, this means that the Monero network updated, and you will need to also update your software in order to be able to sync past that point. However, since the current version on stagenet is v7, it looks like it's just someone having made local modifications, making your node see the new version and thinking it's late, where in fact it's not.

"8(out)+0(in) connections" tells you the number of peer to peer connections your node currently has, sorted by whether your node initiated them, or whether a peer initiated them. If the second number is 0, it mean peers cannot find your node, so your connections to the Monero network is more fragile. You may want to check your router and/or firewall to allow peers to connect to the P2P port (in this case, for stagenet, it is 38081, and it'd be 18081 for mainnet).

Comment: So, as the blockchain is syncing and is growing, the daemon eventually finds blocks that "signal" that starting from this block V7 (for instance) is used?

Comment: Yes. spam for length check.