# Syncing stagenet daemon

Tags: monerod, synchronization, stagenet

I use `Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.3.0-release)` CLI only.

I opened [another thread](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10063/meaning-of-monerod-status-command-output) that might or might not be related to this one.

---

I have 3 stagenet daemons running (for testing purpose, not on the same system), all running the version mentioned above.

2 of them show strange logging lines like these:

`[94.19.172.18:51393 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 136994 -> 250777 [Your node is 113783 blocks (79 days) behind]`

**Strange thing** about this message is, that it shows another block height. In between those messages I can find the *real* log info which says:

`[51.15.235.157:57076 INC]  Synced 137854/146135`

---

When triggering the monerod `status` command both daemons show `V1` (see the [other thread](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10063/meaning-of-monerod-status-command-output)).
The stagenet daemon not producing such messages shows `V7` instead.

This is one obvious difference I could find, but I am not sure what to do about it.

It keeps on displaying those logs even after completing the synchronization. That's why I started all over - to no avail.

---

Additionally every now and then the following message appears in the logs:

`[207.180.196.236:57862 INC]  peer claims higher version that we think (9 for 232290 instead of 7) - we may be forked from the network and a software upgrade may be needed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the daemons claiming to be 79 days behind have found a peer (or peers) which are running a modified version of the monero stagenet protocol, and are therefore unable to sync. They'll only be able to once they find a peer on the correct chain.

Alternatively, it might be a monero fork (since the P2P comms appear to be compatible) and they incompetently failed to modify the network ID.

To try to get out of this mess, you can try manually banning those peers that claim v9:

ban 1.2.3.4

The IPs are in the messages.

One thing isnot clear: what makes you think some of the logs are not real ?

Comment: Sorry, **real** might not be the right choice of words here. I was referring to the actual syncing log messages including the correct block height.